# c# LINQ getting a string that contains all elements in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having trouble coming up with a LINQ to do the following... suppose I have a list of strings below:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.add("one");
strings.add("two");
strings.add("three");
```

I want to be able to get a string that looks like the following:

```
string correctString = "onetwothree";
```

but return null when selecting any other string, e.g.

```
string wrongString1 = "onethree"; // returns null
string wrongString2 = "one"; // returns null
string wrongString3 = "onetwo"; // returns null
string wrongString4 = "five"; // returns null
```

I'm thinking LINQ is the best way to go about it, but unfortunately not having much luck with the select and many statements...

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

[EDIT]
Ok apologies for the confusion...

I wasn't trying to concatenate strings.  I was trying to use a LINQ query to match correctString with the list of strings, e.g.

```
aRandomStringList.FirstOrDefault<string>(st => st.contains(<all the values in the "strings" list>);
```

Given the fact that the values in strings List can change... e.g. "one" and "three" can swap place.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with 'selecting any other string'? Can the user select something? What would be wrong with the other examples?

Comment: beracim -out of interest, what is the use case for the scenario that you describe. perhaps that could be a better starting point for your question. as it stands, you're just gonna get a load of duplicate answers showing how to concatenate your list into a single string. see my 'almost' duplicate answer added below

Comment: @jim tollan: I have updated my question. Basically I want to get a string from a list of strings which contains all of the strings in a custom string List.

Answer (score 0):

To join strings use the `contact` method

```
var correctString = string.Concat(strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

BeraCim,

As per the other answers on the page, here's my twist:

```
var strings = new List<string> 
{
    "one", 
    "two", 
    "three"
};

// concatenate the list to single string
var correctString = string.Concat(strings);

string wrongString1 = "onethree"; // returns null
string wrongString2 = "one";      // returns null
string wrongString3 = "onetwo";   // returns null
string wrongString4 = "five";     // returns null
string correctStringTest = "onetwothree"; // returns "onetwothree"

// will return the value of correctString or null
var result = TestResult(correctString, wrongString1);
```

and the 'test' method:

```
public string TestResult(string sourceTest, string targetTest)
{
    return (sourceTest == targetTest) ? sourceTest : null;
}
```

that should do the trick. not particularly elegant, but based on the question may satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I did not have understand correctly what u need. I think u don't need Linq

```
        List<string> strings = new List<string>();

        private string TestString(string word)
        {
            return strings.IndexOf(word) >= 0 ? strings[strings.IndexOf(word)] : null;
        }
        private void Main()
        {
            strings.AddRange(new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "onetwothree" });
            string[] words = { "onethree", "one", "onetwo", "five", "onetwothree" };
            Console.WriteLine(TestString(words[0]));
            Console.WriteLine(TestString(words[1]));
            Console.WriteLine(TestString(words[2]));
            Console.WriteLine(TestString(words[3]));
            Console.WriteLine(TestString(words[4]));
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string [] sArr = new string [10];

        for (int i = initVal; i < initVal + 10; i++)
            sArr[i - initVal] = String.Format("{0,-3}", i * multVal);

        return String.Join(sep, sArr);
```

like above

```
  string correctString =   string.Join("",strings.ToArray());
```